# Global monotonicity of locally monotone function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and locally increasing, that is, for all $x \in [0,1)$, there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $f$ is monotone increasing on $[x,x+\varepsilon]$.  Is $f$ monotone increasing on $[0,1]$?

Comment: So $f(1)$ can be anything?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I require $f$ to be continuous, so $f(1)$ is not a free choice.

Comment: Please see the edit of my answer

Comment: @John:  Thanks, this is very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assertion is true if you assume continuity of $f$.

Pick $0\leq x <y \leq 1$, we want to show $f(x) \leq f(y)$. Let $M$ be the maximum of $f$ inside the closed interval $[x, y]$. Let $A = \{ t\in [x, y]: f(t) = M\}$. Then $A$ is nonempty as $[x, y]$ is closed and $f$ continuous. Also $A$ is a closed set as $f$ is continuous.

Let $z \in [x, y]$ be the supremum of $A$. Then $z\in A$ as $A$ is closed. But if $z\neq y$, then there is $\epsilon>0$ small so that $z+ \epsilon <y$ and

$$M \geq f(z+ \epsilon) \geq f(z) = M$$

This implies $z+\epsilon \in A$ and that's violate the definition of $z$. Thus $z=y$ and

$$f(y) = M \geq f(x).$$

Comment: Thanks, but I wrote "increasing" to mean "non-decreasing".  So this rather nice argument doesn't work.

Comment: @Victor: Please see the edit again.

Answer (score 0):

Define:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x &\text{if} &0 \leq x < 1 \\
0 &\text{if} &x = 1
\end{cases}
$$
This function is monotonically increasing for $x \in [0,1)$, but not for $x \in [0,1]$.